# How to setup an AdSense crawler login that supports a range of dynamic URLs?

Tags: google-adsense, web-crawlers, dynamic

I have a website that largely features dynamic content. Every piece of dynamic content has it's own URL, such as "`www.example.com/page/\*/\*`"

The problem I have is that many of these pages require a user to be logged in. I have read about AdSense crawler login, and tried to implement it. However, I can find no mention of wildcards or regular expressions for the URL. As far as I can tell, AdSense crawler login only supports static URLs.

Is there any way to setup an AdSense crawler login that supports a range of dynamic URLs?

Answer (score 1):

From [the AdSense help page](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/161351?hl=en) it says that they support entire directories that need login:

> You'll need to provide the following information:
>
> - Restricted directory or URL: The URL that is blocked from our crawler's access.
> - ...

So you could tell them that `/page/` requires login.    If there are other pages in that directory that don't *require* login, AdSense crawler would also fetched them logged in.